# Create temporary URL to download files

Tags: php

I am making a project in which I will send File URL on mail to download the file.

For hosting my files I am using Mega and saved Mega file's URL to the database.

The script will fetch the Mega file's URL from the database, but here I want to shorten the Mega file's URL to make it available for 3 hours only and after that, shorten URL will expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create any random URL you want on your server, map it to the entry in the database and if someone requests the URL during the time it's valid redirect the request to the actual mega URL you store in the database.

How you decide to "shorten" the URL is up to you and depends mostly on aesthetics.

Perhaps one wants

> www.mysit.com/file.php?uid=8s9f1e3f2v78d9f172fd3easvcd9871

or

> www.mysite.com/ge723gdn328

etc.

When you store a file store the time it should be valid until the actual URL it points to and the unique id of the file which will be part of the "shortened" URL you provide. For instance, it could be a hash (or some friendly identifier) of the URL of the actual file and then you will be quite certain it's unique.

When a request is made, grab the unique id, fetch the data from the database, redirect (or proxy) the contents of the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Bitly for shorten the URL. You need to register with them and get access token.

Using below URL you can generate the short URL. You just need to pass long URL as input with an access token.

https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F

OR

```
/* returns the shortened url */
function get_bitly_short_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format='txt') {
    $connectURL = 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&uri='.urlencode($url).'&format='.$format;
    return curl_get_result($connectURL);
}

/* returns expanded url */
function get_bitly_long_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format='txt') {
    $connectURL = 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/expand?login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&shortUrl='.urlencode($url).'&format='.$format;
    return curl_get_result($connectURL);
}

/* returns a result form url */
function curl_get_result($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

/* get the short url */
$short_url = get_bitly_short_url('https://google.com/','loginname','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

/* get the long url from the short one */
$long_url = get_bitly_long_url($short_url,'loginname','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea for solution would be for you to add new column in database where you store Mega file's URL, something like '`shortURL`', where you will generate some string and save it there. Then, when user accesses '`yourdomain.com/randomString`', he/she will be redirected to the Mega file's URL. Last thing you'd need to do is a `cron job` that will run on server, and would delete the shorURL after some time (3 hours). If user accesses the '`yourdomain.com/randomString`' after the time is up, he will be redirected to homepage or error page will appear saying that the link has expired.

I guess there are some other ways to do what you want, but this is the first one that comes to my mind.